# How to present bitstring in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

How to present bitstring in SQLite3 ? I am using SQLite Maestro and I don't see bitstring type. What type to choose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLOB for binary data...

While SQLite does have a few basic bit-wise operators (that only work on data convertible to a NUMERIC), it is pretty much *up to the client* on how to handle the "bitstring" -- so check on how the *client* works and what back-end formats are utilitized. (For instance, bitstrings of no more than 64 elements can be saved in an INTEGER field.)

All the SQLite types and type affinities are [discussed here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in a fair bit of detail.

Happy SQL'ing.